# Google script. Creat trigger automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am new in js and it is my first script. The idea of my project is creat event in my google calander every time when I edit (write values) to some cell. The problem is that I can't use onEdit() function because I need permission (use calander from sheet level). So I creat installable trigger like this:

```
function createEditTrigger() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('ToCalendar')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

Everything is fine but now I want creat this trigger automatically to my sheet not manually like I have now.

My idea was to use function onOpen() like this:

```
function onOpen() {
   createEditTrigger();
  Logger.log("hi");
}
```

but it of course will creat many the same triggers.

Is there any way to creat trigger automatically only once? 
I will be grateful for all answers!

Comment: I want do this because I want share my sheet with script to to other colleagues and I don't want them to have to manually add a trigger. You are right onOpen doesn't work, my bad. Sorry if I write some silly things but but it's all new for me :/

Comment: If Google allowed this and assuming you're a evil mastermind, You'll be able to steal anything from your colleague's google account without them being aware-just by sharing a sheet with edit privileges. Get it? You can't sneak up a script behind them...  Google can't allow that(at least, not that easily)There needs to be some manual work on their part.  You can write a custom menu(for the auth flow)/publish a add-on, so as to allow them to auth your script and let them inform google that they trust that you're not a evil mastermind.

Comment: Oh I get it,  seems that you are right. Thanks for this comment. I will do as you wrote. Thank you :)